# how to create custom form validation with j query on submit

Tags: jquery, forms, validation

i have a form that inputs name, last name , amount, personal id, comments.
i need to validate that the field amount so the value cant be lower than 20.

this is the form

```
  <form name="myForm"class="form-signup" id ="req-form" action="reg_form.php"   method="post">
        <div class="form-group">
    <label for="fname">First Name:</label><span style="color:red;" id="ferror"> </span>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="fname" id="fname"  value="<?php echo "$user_fname";?>">

    <label for="lname">Last Name:</label><span style="color:red;" id="lerror"> </span>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="lname" id="lname" value="<?php echo "$user_lname";?>">



     <label for="amount">Amount:</label><span style="color:red;" id="aerror"> </span>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="amount"  required id="amount" placeholder="Amount">

    <label for="cedula">personal id:</label><span style="color:red;" id="cferror"> </span>
    <input class="form-control" type="text" name="cedula" id="cedula" value="<?php echo "$user_cedula";?>">

<label for="cedula">comments:</label><span style="color:red;" id="coferror"> </span>
  <input class="form-control" type="text" name="comments" id="comments" placeholder="comments optional">

<input class="btn btn-warning" type="submit"  value="Submit"  name="myButton" >

 </div>     
</form> 

     <script>
   $(document).ready(function(e){
   $('#req-form').on('submit',function(){
    alert( $('#amount').val() );
    });
  });

 $('#req-form').submit(function(){
$this = $(this);

/** prevent double posting */
if ($this.data().isSubmitted) {
    return false;
}

/** do some processing */

/** mark the form as processed, so we will not process it again */
$this.data().isSubmitted = true;

return true;
  });


  </script>
```

i need to prevent amount be less than 20 and i need to avoid multiple submit when user's click submit, so far i got it working all i need to do now is avoid amount to be less than 20, so far the validation i got it to alert the amount now i need to validate it, did validate with java script but for some reason it was validating the fields but did not avoid multiple submits, so i will like to  code everything with jquery

Answer (score 0):

hope it help anyone, i solved it my self using  if statement, validate amount field avoiding user to input amount below 20 and avoid multiples submits

```
<script>
 $(document).ready(function(e){
 $('#req-form').on('submit',function(){
        var $inp = $('#amount').val() ;
        if ( $inp < 20)
        {
            alert( 'you request cant be lower than 20' );
            return false;
        }

});
});

 $('#req-form').submit(function(){
$this = $(this);

 if ($this.data().isSubmitted) {
    return false;
}

 $this.data().isSubmitted = true;

return true;
 });


 </script>
```